# Phonegap image upload fails during second time

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on mobile application for Android. In this I am trying to capture an image and upload it to the server. Image is getting uploaded the first time but its not getting uploaded the second time and is returning a FileTransfer - Error Code 3.

My code from the app is below-

```
 var name=window.localStorage.getItem('image_name');
 var path = window.localStorage.getItem('image_path');

 // initializing file transfer object
    var product_ft = new FileTransfer();    
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="image";
    options.fileName=name;
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.fullpath = path;
    params.name = name;
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;


    // uploads image
    url = "http://...";
    product_ft.upload( path, url,
    function(response) 
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response['response']);
        window.localStorage.setItem('image_server_path',obj.image_path);

    },
    function(error) {
        //upload unsuccessful, error occured while upload.
        error("Error uploading image. We're sorry for this. Can you please try again?", 'Image Not Saved');
    },
    options
    );
```

LogCat is showing following error--

```
{"target":"http:\/\/...","source":"file:\/\/\/mnt\/sdcard\/DCIM\/Camera\/1378965045896.jpg","http_status":0,"code":3}
{java.io.EOFException}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:314)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:301)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:130)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:630)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:385)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:334)}
{at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)}
{at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:455)}
{at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)}
{at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)}
{at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)} 
{Failed after uploading 26517 of 26517 bytes.}
```

Am I missing something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code and try this. Its working fine in the cordova version 2.9.0.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
}
options.chunkedMode = false;

ft.upload(imgUrl, PATH, uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options);
```